# How is map implemented internally?

Tags: haskell

Ok so i want to implement my custom map that receives a replication factor and a target list.

Inputs:  `Int -> [Int]`
Output: `[[Int]]`
E.g.:  `2 [1,2]    -----> [[1,1],[2,2]]`

`f [1,2,3]` -> map -> `[f(1),f(2),f(3)]`

What is supposed to happen with f(1) when map goes to the next element of the list?How should  i replace 1 with f(1) ?

P.S: This was my initial solution but it does replicate the initial list,not every element.

```
replicate::Int->[Int]->[[Int]]
replicate 1 x=x
replicate factor (x:xs)= go factor [] (x:xs) where
                         go factor ls (x:xs) =go factor (repl factor x):ls xs 
                         repl 1 nr=nr
                         repl times nr=nr:repl (times-1) nr
```

Comment: Note: “Inputs: `Int -> [Int]`, Outputs: `[[Int]]`” suggests the function is supposed to have signature `(Int -> [Int]) -> [[Int]]`, which is very different from `Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]`. The latter is actually parsed as `Int -> ([Int] -> [[Int]])`, which [uncurries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) to `(Int, [Int]) -> [[Int]]`.

Comment: Yes but since i defined no external method i just placed the initial parameters and the final result.

Comment: But _did you_? The initial parameters have types `Int` and `[Int]`. None of them has the function type `Int -> [Int]`. This kind of distinction is important.

Comment: Well i do not have to specifiy the type of a function defined inside a where clause or a let am i right?It's an auxiliary method.

Comment: No, you don't need to specify local types, but you should always have a clear idea what type you want.

Comment: You should omit types when you are very confident about what they are, they would not provide any significant code documentation, and you think you could easily write them -- but it would be a waste of time/effort. Instead, when the type is not very clear, even in a `where` clause, I would recommend to write explicit type annotations. Usually, an approach such as "I don't understand this, so I'll omit it, and hope for the best" is not very successful.

Comment: @chi, following that advice often requires `ScopedTypeVariables` in polymorphic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> custom map that receives a replication factor and a target list

It is a little unclear to me what you're asking for.

Does `mymap` receive the replication factor, or does `f`?

> E.g.: `2 [1,2]    -----> [[1,1],[2,2]]`

If you want `mymap 2 [1,2]` to give `[[1,1],[2,2]]`, then:

```
mymap :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mymap = map . replicate
```

However,

> ```
> mymap :: (Int -> [Int]) -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
> ```

How is this function any different from the built-in `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` with `a` as `Int` and `b` as `[Int]`? Here, `mymap` does not have any `Int` argument itself, so you must mean that `f`'s argument is the replication factor; but if `f 2 3 == [3,3]`, then `f` *is* `replicate` and you can use the solution above.

You can write this using your own recursive definitions, if you like:

```
mymap :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mymap _ [] = []
mymap n (x:xs) = myreplicate n x : mymap n xs

myreplicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
myreplicate 0 _ = []
myreplicate n x = x : myreplicate (n-1) x
```

Or you can use list comprehension instead of a `map`:

```
mymap :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
mymap n xs = [ replicate n x | x <- xs ]
```

I'd probably call `mymap` for `replicateMany` or something like that.

Comment: I thought that you can implement map without cons-ing on the list.I thought you could somehow replace all elements of a list with something else.

Comment: No, under the hood `map` definitely needs to deconstruct its input using the `:` pattern constructor and reconstruct its result using the `:` value constructor (operator). Once you have enough useful higher-order functions like `map` and `replicate`, you can leverage them to avoid writing **explicit** cons-ing, but they still occur under the hood.

Comment: This was the holy-grail explanation i was looking for :D Thank you sir.I thought you can just   [(insert here),(insert here),(insert here)]

Comment: You can only do so for lists of a fixed length.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Even `[foo, bar, baz]` is just a pretty syntax for calls to `:`; specifically, `foo:bar:baz:[]`.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues, that prevent your code from compiling:

1. `null` function has the type `[a0] -> Bool`, but you're applying it
       on an element of a list, hence you're expecting it to be `Int -> Bool`
2. The result `f x` shouldn't be pushed into the tail of the input, it
   should be pushed into the result of recursive call of the function:
   `f x: (mymap f xs)` instead of `f x: xs`

As a result the following code should work:

```
mymap :: (Int -> [Int]) -> [Int]-> [[Int]]
mymap f (x:xs) = if null xs then [] else f x : (mymap f xs)
```

By the way, the Standard Library provides much readable (and also polymorphic) [implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map) using pattern-matching:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```